# iOS - Replace Siri with Google Assistant

Tags: iphone, ios, google-voice

I have been using both Siri and Google Assistant. Between the two, I find latter to be more smarter and prefer it over the former.

Is there a way to replace Siri with Google Assistant? If yes, how do I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siri and Google Assistant are similar offerings from Apple and Google and are deeply integrated in their respective mobile OS. It is **not possible** to replace one with the other.

While Siri is exclusive to iOS (along with other OS by Apple macOS, watchOS and tvOS), Google provides the Google Assistance app for iOS.

Google Assistant app for iOS can be downloaded on [iTunes App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/the-google-assistant-get-help-anytime-anywhere/id1220976145).

On an additional note, as Siri is deeply integrated into iOS, there are various features exclusive to it, which Google Assistant cannot perform on iOS.

Comment: Yes I actually installed it and I find it way more better than siri. Tysm for your information.